# Resources exceeded during a query execution when building a derived table

Tags: google-bigquery

Table structure:. 
  InvoiceLineKey(string),
      Revenue(float),
      COGS(float),
      Cost1(float),
      Cost2(float),
      Cost3(float),
      Cost4(float),
      Cost5(float),
      Proft(float),
      QSPEC(float).

Number of rows : 60,000,000 records

SELECT
      InvoiceLineKey,
      Revenue,
      COGS,
      Cost1,
      Cost2,
      Cost3,
      Cost4,
      Cost5,
      Proft,
      "" AS QSPEC,
      RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Revenue DESC) AS Ranking,
      SUM(Revenue) OVER(ORDER BY Revenue DESC) AS CumulativeRevenue
    FROM
      [pi-training:training.training_fact]
    WHERE
      Revenue > 0
    ORDER BY
      Revenue DESC
The query failed failed with the error:

> Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be
>   executed in the allotted memory. ORDER BY operator used too much
>   memory..

Comment: Can you include the exact error messages output?  Or is "Resources exceeded during query execution" all you get?

Comment: Query Failed
Error: Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. ORDER BY operator used too much memory..

Comment: How many rows are in the table? Do you get the same error when using standard SQL? (I'm assuming you will, but it's worth checking).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I marked your code as code sample and included the error. But your question still needs to be more specific e.g. describe data you are processing.

Comment: Yes same error with standard SQL . Table :60,000,000 records

Comment: Table structure ,    
  InvoiceLineKey(string), Revenue(float), 
  COGS(float),    
  Cost1(float),    
  Cost2(float),    
  Cost3(float),    
  Cost4(float),    
  Cost5(float),    
  Proft(float),    
   QSPEC(string)

Comment: It is much better to edit the question than add details to comments. Please try to imagine somebody trying to answer your question. The person needs to get all information quickly otherwise goes away.

Comment: Added successfully, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that `InvoiceLineKey` is about 8 bytes in size (the same size as the floating point columns), 60 million rows means that the result size is about 4.8 gigabytes. The [documentation on "Managing Query Outputs" for BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-output#use_a_limit_clause_with_large_sorts) explains that when using `ORDER BY` over a large dataset, you should include a `LIMIT` or a filter.

In your case, supposing that about a tenth of `Revenue` values are greater than 10000, and these are the ones that you want to return, you could use `WHERE Revenue >= 10000` to restrict the number of rows to sort to a smaller subset of the data.